# I'm trying to upload large files via ajax but im getting "Error: Request entity too large"

Tags: php, apache

I´ve got my limitrequestbody set to 0 on apache and on phpI have post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to 50M and max_input_time to 2 m. But when I try to upload a file of 4 mb I get this error. I have a hosting account on godaddy.

My .user.ini has these lines

```
upload_max_filesize = 50M
post_max_size = 50M
max_input_time = 130
```

and my .htaccess

```
LimitRequestBody 0
```

Comment: Hi! Are you using php? If yes, try look the limit there

Comment: All my limits are set exactly as I'm setting them

Comment: In Debian the main PHP config file is located in the /etc/php5/apache/php.ini. Have you tried to set in?